# How do reduce complexity with async function in this case?

Tags: node.js, express

I have an Express app and some function in  server.js code is like this:

```
server.post('/post', (req, res) => {
    //some code here...
    function a() {
        return new Promise(resolve => {
            //some code here...
            resolve(`result`)
        });
    };
    
    async function output() {
        console.log('Waiting');
        const result = await a();
        console.log(result);
        //some code here...
    };
    output();
});
```

It works good but too nested to read. I want to move the `function a()` outside the `server.post` like:

```
function a() {
      return new Promise(resolve => {
      //some code here...
      resolve(`result`)
    });
}

server.post('/post', (req, res) => {
    //some code here...
    
    a();

    async function output() {
        console.log('Waiting');
        const result = await a();
        console.log(result);
        //some code here...
    };
    output();
});
```

But like this cannot work as before...

In this case how to reduce the complexity of the first example?

Comment: Declaring and then immediately running a function is usually pointless, excepting really strange scoping issues.

Comment: Can you provide an example that's more like your real functions? The current example has no need for the functions but I assume `a` has a callback that relies on `req` to get the `result`?

Comment: Yes it is. actually function a() use another api to fetch some data to the server. I need to wait the data finished then can move to the next process output().

Answer (score 1):

You can usually handle it with this pattern:

```js
server.post('/post', async (req, res, next) => {
    // Some async code here

    let stuff = await example();
    await a(stuff);

    res.send(...);

    next();
});
```

The key here is to have a `next` argument so you can chain through when the promises wrap up. This is a callback function that must be called. Failing to call it leaves your request hanging.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but my problem is not because of this. I think it's some scoping issue but I cannot figure it out.

Comment: You're going to have to explain what the issue is. This pattern is a lot simpler than the one you had sketched out.

Comment: As a note there's really no need to go and make a Promise manually if you can instead make an `async function()` that does the same thing.

Comment: OH I understand what you said.. I will try it , thx!